# When does $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{b}^{a_n}f_n(x)dx=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_b^\infty f_n(x)dx$ hold?

Tags: calculus, limits, integration, convergence-divergence

Let $\{a_n\}\subset \mathbb{R}$ be sequence and $$f_n:[b,\infty)\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}, \qquad n=1,2,\dots .$$
Assume that $$\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}a_n=+\infty.$$
Obviously, from the definition $\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\int_{b}^{a_n}g(x)dx=\int_{b}^{\infty}g(x)dx.$
I am interested about conditions to set of functions $\{f_n\},$ when the following is true:
$$\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\int_{b}^{a_n}f_n(x)dx=\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\int_b^\infty f_n(x)dx.$$

Comment: A trivial case is where $f_1 \equiv f_2 \equiv ...$ and we know that $\int^{\infty}_{b} f_1 $ exists, but otherwise, I have no clue. Maybe as a way of attacking the problem, I would see what conditions on the $f_n$ we require in order that the LHS and RHS limits exist, and then deal with when they are equal.

Answer (score 1):

The a.e. pointwise convergence of $(f_n)$ and th existence of a dominating function $\varphi$ is sufficient. Here, we say that $\varphi$ dominates $(f_n)$ if

1. $\int_{b}^{\infty} \varphi < \infty$ and
2. $\left| f_n \right| \leq \varphi$ a.e. for all $n$.

Indeed, notice that

$$ \int_{b}^{a_n} f_n = \int_{b}^{\infty} f_n \chi_{[b, a_n]}. $$

Thus the sequence $\tilde{f}_n = f_n \chi_{[b, a_n]}$ converges pointwise to $\lim_{n} f_n$ a.e. and is dominated by $\varphi$ as well, and hence the conclusion follows by the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Just the existence of dominating function is sufficient; a.e. convergence is needless here.

Comment: The dominating function obviously only needs to dominate on some tail (this might be relevant in some special cases).

Comment: You're right. That conditions are nothing but excessive. We can replace this by a mere convergence of the integrals $\int_{b}^{\infty} f_n$.

Comment: It should be emphasized that this is only true for lebesgue integrals, though. The distinction is important here, because there are riemann integrals with infinite bounds which don't exist as lebesgue integrals. (This happens if convergence of the riemann integral depends on positive and negativ parts cancelling each other).